# Perpetual loading bar in modifier options on CP

Tags: expresso-store

I'm having an issue with Store when adding a modifier to any item. I've used Store successfully until now but since adding new channels to the site there's a glitch that I just can't get around. When I add a new product modifier and enter a name, the 'stock' area below shows a loading bar but doesn't do anything.

I'm able to click on submit but the product details aren't saved. This is now the same across the whole site and I have no idea why.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I've tried with a blank .htaccess file and using store version 1.6.4. It works fine on a different host but the client is with 1&1 and it just doesn't seem to work.

**Edit**

After looking at the firebug console when this issue arises I see "Post my/url/path?ACT=26 200 OK" When I look at this post, I can see the 'response header' says "no-cache, must revalidate".

Still really stuck on this.

**Edit 2**

Right, I think I just solved the problem. It turns out it was some kind of problem with the way 1&1 handled requests without the 'www' portion of a url. I added the following lines to my .htaccess file and all now seems to be working

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Thank god.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right, I think I just solved the problem. It turns out it was some kind of problem with the way 1&1 handled requests without the 'www' portion of a url. I added the following lines to my .htaccess file and all now seems to be working

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Thank god.

Comment: This sounds right. Browsers can't make ajax requests between www and no-www domains (they count as separate domains), so you need to make sure your htaccess matches what your EE site URL is set to.